# Browsing skill with Semantic Kernel (ChatGPT)

Tags: c#, browser, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I created skill for browsing which works well (browser opens, chatGPT navigate it to url and could provide actions on page).
Problem is, that ChatGPT is not aware of page of itself, I guess it could help if I send html to chatGPT, but I don't know how do it.

Could you help me?
[Repo with BrowserSkill.cs](https://gitlab.com/Dave3991/semantickernel/-/blob/master/src/Modules/SemanticKernel/Domain/Skills/BrowserSkill.cs)

I try to send html code of the loaded page to chatGPT, but it doesnt work because of lenght. And in the end in simulation, chatGPT sends me wrong xPath, not based on HTML I provided.

Answer (score 1):

When exposing the skill as a ChatGPT plugin, the SK functions will run in the hosting environment, not within the browser's scope. Note that driving the browser on your local machine may work, but it won't work once deployed to a VM in the cloud.

To have ChatGPT pass the URL, ensure that the plugin JSON schema files include the parameter. Check the OpenAPI file to see if it correctly reflects the input parameters.

Regarding the `BrowseToUrl` definition, it should only expect the URL to navigate to, not the source HTML and error URL input. I would revise the function accordingly.